# read swapchain color in fragment shader in vulkan

Tags: vulkan

i try doing some blend functions like overlay. it can't be implemented in blend stage because i need to know the color i want to blend in the position in last draw. Is there any solution for getting the color of last draw in fragment shader in vulkan ?

i try using two render pass A and B. each has one framebuffer a and b. A receives B's framebuffer b as A's input and outputs to b. B receives A's framebuffer a as B's input and outputs to b. when i need blend, i swap A and B. and finally copy a or b to framebuffer from swapchain. but i have'nt make it until now.

Comment: SO is for programming questions

Comment: yeah. i have added the tag "vulkan"

Comment: Cn we see the code?

Comment: sorry, its too much.

Comment: That's why you need to add only [mre]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While your proposed setup is functional, it's not efficient. If you're just trying to read from the texel that corresponds to the fragment position (ie: the one your fragment shader invocation is going to overwrite), then what you want is an input attachment.

Your subpass should set the attachment to be both a color attachment and an input attachment (which requires the "general" image layout). This allows you to do a read from the input attachment (which can only read the texel corresponding to your fragment) and write to the FS output that gets written to the output attachment. Which is the same image.

*However*, this is not a free pass to arbitrary read/modify/write blending. You only get to do a read/modify/write *once* for each pixel. If you want to do another RMW for the same pixel, you *must* submit a pipeline barrier between the two drawing commands, and the subpass must have a subpass self-dependency.

This also means that no single drawing command can have overlapping triangles in them. So this can complicate blending, but that's usually par-for-the-course for blending.